# Как заставить тряпичную куклу(ragdoll) стоять в Юнити 3д?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь заставить стоять рэгдол(тряпичную куклу) по [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60ZuchTb0BUhttps://). Однако есть отличие - я делаю это в 3D, а на видео 2D. В классе muscle выходит ошибка(moveRotation), помогите пожалуйста с ней. Не понимаю.

Мой говнокод написанный в блокноте:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60ZuchTb0BU
    public Muscle[] muscles;


    void Update()
    {
       foreach (Muscle muscle in muscles)
       {
          muscle.ActivateMuscle();
       }
    }
}

[System.Serializable] 

public class Muscle
{
    public Rigidbody bone;
    public float restRotation; 
    public float force;
    
    public void ActivateMuscle()
    {
       bone.MoveRotation(Mathf.LerpAngle(bone.rotation, restRotation, force * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> Assets/player.cs(30,42): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'float'

Что-то связано с аргументами, но что - не понимаю

Comment: `LerpAngle` смотрите аргументы, и сравнивайте типы с тем, что вы указали

Comment: Тряпичная кукла XD